# Multiple labels

Tags: c#, label

I want to use multiple labels in my form. I am using the following code:

```
 Label[] lblLeftUp = new Label[12];
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
 {
    lblLeftUp[i] = new Label();
    lblLeftUp[i].Location = new Point((100 + (20 * i)), 100);
    lblLeftUp[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
    this.Controls.Add(lblLeftUp[i]);
 }
```

however, I can see only one label. any idea to fix that?

Comment: in what page event are you doing this ?

Comment: You forgot to set the Size.  20 * i isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels are blocking eachother. So try this:

```
lblLeftUp[i].AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: I was interested by this. So I tried it. So it doesn't matter, there is no differences between use it or not. Because, when you create the label you don't set the size of the label, so I think it's set by default on true.

Comment: No I tested your code and it worked for me. I think AutiSize = false by default.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of `lblLeftUp[i].Location = new Point((100 + (20 * i)), 100);`.
How you can see, you set the wrong location for the following labels. Infact *20* isn't enough. So my recommendation is to set the location dipending on the size of the labels. So if you want the labels oredered in horizontal. Try this:

```
Label[] lblLeftUp = new Label[12];
int PointX = 100; //100 is the initial distance from the left border of the control
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
   lblLeftUp[i] = new Label();
   lblLeftUp[i].Location = new Point(PointX, 100);
   lblLeftUp[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
   this.Controls.Add(lblLeftUp[i]);
   PointX += lblLeftUp[i].Width;
}
```